# Concurrently writing and reading from map causes potential race condition

Tags: http, go, concurrency, race-condition

I have a very basic Golang application that creates and runs a HTTP server. The server has 2 endpoints, one to send data and one to receive.

Upon each POST request to the server, parse the incoming data from the body and push it onto a channel. I then have a function that reads from the channel and saves the data to a map.

Upon each GET request to the server, JSON marshal the map and send it to the client.

Each request to the HTTP server runs asynchronously and the worker function writes to the map synchronously in its own goroutine.

Basic pseudo code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

type dataStore map[string]string

func listenHandler(stream chan string) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // JSON unmarshal request body

        // push data onto stream
        stream <- data
    }
}

func serveHandler(store *dataStore) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // JSON marshal data store
        // serve to client
    }
}

func worker(stream <-chan string) *dataStore {
    store := make(dataStore)
    go func() {
        for data := range stream {
            // process and write data to map
        }
    }()
    return &store
}

func main() {
    stream := make(chan string)
    store := worker(stream)

    http.HandleFunc("/listen", listenHandler(stream))
    http.HandleFunc("/serve", serveHandler(store))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I have tested and ran the application with no problems, however I have been told it has a potential race condition and I am not sure why. Is this true?

Comment: Have you built and run your code with `-race` option?

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur yes on both build an test and it runs fine.

Comment: You have no synchronization around your map, and it could be modified and read concurrently.

Comment: @JimB makes sense after your edit. You had me confused.

Comment: @JimB so I will need a mutex around the map if I want to concurrently read and write?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/go1.6#runtime "As always, if one goroutine is writing to a map, no other goroutine should be reading or writing the map concurrently. If the runtime detects this condition, it prints a diagnosis and crashes the program."

Comment: @danbondd you can use any synchronisation mechanism that lets you achieve the expected behaviour (no writes concurrent to any other operation). For example: mutexes, yes.

Comment: @zerkms Ok, thanks. I'm still a little unsure as to why it was never flagged when I ran the application with the `-race` flag.

Comment: @danbondd: no data structures in go are safe for concurrent reads and writes. You always need synchronization.

Comment: @danbondd: the race detector and runtime map checks can only detect races when they happen, if you don't test your code with concurrent requests, then there's no concurrent access.

Comment: @JimB Makes sense, thanks! I only tested the application in isolation without and concurrent end-to-end test.

Comment: Use a read-write lock instead of a mutex.  It allows for concurrents reads and only locks when a goroutine is writing to the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code given, you're only synchronizing your writes, not your reads; that means you still might read from the map while you're writing to it, which would be a race condition.

To make it thread-safe, you need to wrap both reads and writes in a concurrency structure - either using channels or a mutex - in order to ensure that only one thread is accessing it at any given time if it is a write operation. Multiple threads can safely read at the same time, as long as no thread is writing to it. `RWMutex` provides this functionality explicitly.

Comment: Right. Which is what I was trying to get across. How was it unclear?

Comment: "You're only synchronizing your writes, not your reads. That means you still might read from the map while you're writing to it." is an accurate description of the code in the question, and description of the problem with it.

Comment: No, the suggestion follows "To make it thread-safe..." I'll edit for clarity.